# Requesting a few novice LATEX help

Tags: texworks

Just starting to learn LATEX

The image indicating the numbers of my request

My problem with the corresponding numbers.

I want to remove the bullet dot

I want to make it a justified comments

Need to have a centerline (Example (GitHub LinkedIn link)

Want to remove the bullet and heading ("responsibilities")

Please also share resources that I can consult for similar problems.

The latex file

https://file.io/hxVidmFWhIOP (Updated)

I am using the texworks software

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Sourabh Bajaj
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}
\newcommand{\Item}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{#2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}


\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

%----------HEADING-----------------
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
  \textbf{\href{}{\Large XXXXXXX}} & Email : \href{mailto:XXXXXX}{XXXXXX}\\
  \href{}{XXXXX} & Mobile : XXXXX \\
\end{tabular*}

 \resumeItemListStart
 \Item
\makebox     
{3+ years of experiences in process industries, and 4+ years of research experience. Process engineering experiences in the largest EPC brand, adept on process development, process improvement, throughput increase. Experiences of designing and operation of adsorbtion, distillation columns and utility system. Knowlegable in. Proven record of technical and scientific writing, preparing-publishing scientific papers and conference presentations from lab/research findings}
\resumeItemListEnd

%-----------EXPERIENCE-----------------
\section{Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Auburn University}{Auburn, AL}
      {Research Assistant}{Aug 2020 - Present}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities }
          {Graduate research on computational modeling and machine learning for process systems and molecular design}
        \resumeItem{Derivative Free Optimization (DFO)}
          {Developed Aspen Plus process simulation and automated the process simulation for assessing cost comparison at a wide range of inlet flow rate and hydrogen sulfide concentration. DFO  a balck-box optimization suite named RBFopt is used to optimize the annualized cost function of intensified chemical process. The optimization function contained twenty decision variables. }
        \resumeItem{Competing Technology Comparison}
          {Cost-effective technologies are identified among the competing technologies for both conventional and modulerized configuration. The uncertainties of significant parameters were propagated to estimate the uncertainty of cost for each process. }
        \resumeItem{Flexibility Analysis}
          {Derivative Free Optimization of Intensified Chemical Process: Balck-box optimization suite  RBFopt  is used to optimize the annualized cost function  }
      \resumeItemListEnd


   \resumeSubheading
      {Yeungnam University}{Auburn, AL}
      { Research Assistant}{Aug 2019 -Aug 2020}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          {Procesdifferent nanomaterial synthesis procedures such as microwave, hydrothermal, chemical vapor deposition, and self-assembly. Used tube furnace, ISCO pump (supercritical CO2), microwave reactor, tip ultrasonicator, vacuum oven, cryo refrigerator, freeze dryer, vacuum evaporator, and centrifuge Performed various characterization techniques (i.e. SEM, TEM, AFM, XRD, NMR, XPS, FTIR, EDS, TGA, GC, EIS, UV-VIS, ICP-AES }
        \resumeItem{Courses}
          {cc}
      \resumeItemListEnd


    \resumeSubheading
      {Syngenta}{Chittagong, Bangladesh}
      {Senior Production Officer}{Feb 2019 - May 2019}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          { Performed documentation for standard audits (JSA , WRA, CRA,  PPE audits etc). Developed visual management in production line (ie Pictorial SOPs). Trained operation team on standard operating procedures. Implemented  product and process compliance and adherence to Syngenta CoP. Ensured work place safety and effective communication of Safety, Health and Environment to all team members.}
 \resumeItem{Projects}
          {Installation of Boshch Packaging Equipment}
      \resumeItemListEnd

    \resumeSubheading
      {ZICOM Equipment Pte. Ltd.}{Dhaka, Bangladesh}
      {Process Engineer}{Jun 2012- Dec 2014}
      \resumeItemListStart
        \resumeItem{Responsibilities}
          {Commissioned process plant. troubleshooted process operation \& PLC-HMI. Conversent with Alen Bradley Control Logics. PID Control loop, DMC, Process Optimization }
        \resumeItem{Projects}
          {Condensate Fractionation Plant; Silicagel Dehydration Type Natural Gas Process Plant; Teg Type Natural Gas Process Plant }
      \resumeItemListEnd



  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

%-----------SKILLS-----------------
\section{Skills}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
  \resumeSubItem{PLCs}
      {Rockwell PLCs }
  \resumeSubItem{GMP}
      {Rudimentary Krowldge on ICHQ7 "Overview of ICH Q7 Online Training Course" Parenteral Drug Association }
  \resumeSubItem{Programming}
   { Python, Matlab, Machine learning, LaTeX}
  \resumeSubItem{Process Simulation}
      {Aspen HYSYS , Aspen Plus, PYPESIM. Heat exchanger Design: HTRI Certified  (Jakarta, Indonesia), Aspen Exchanger Design \& Rating (EDR). Aspen Economic Analyzer (Graduate course), AutoCAD, Visio.}

  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%-----------EDUCATION-----------------
\section{Education}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeSubheading
      {Auburn University}{Auburn, AL}
      {Doctor of Philosophy in Chemical Engineering; (Ongoing)}{Aug 2019 -- Present}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Yeungnam University}{Gyeongsan, South Korea}
      {Master of Science in Chemical Engineering;  GPA: 4.31/4.50}{Aug 2016 -- Feb 2018}
    \resumeSubheading
      {Bangladesh University of Engineering and Technology}{Dhaka, Bangladesh}
      {Bachelor of Science in Chemical Engineering;  GPA: 3.22/4.00}{Aug 2008 -- Mar 2012}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd



%
%--------PROGRAMMING SKILLS------------
%\section{Programming Skills}
%  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
%    \item{
%      \textbf{Languages}{: Scala, Python, Javascript, C++, SQL, Java}
%      \hfill
%      \textbf{Technologies}{: AWS, Play, React, Kafka, GCE}
%    }
%  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd


%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: The linked LaTeX file appears to have been deleted from the file.io server.

Comment: show your text inline in the question using the `{}` code button in the editor don't use external links that may break over time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Devid and @Dan I have updated according to both of your suggestion

Comment: What image? I see no image in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are just starting out with LaTeX, I would recommend starting out with a simpler template. The following code's output looks very similar to what you have, but you might find it easier to use.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}%Make itemize environment more compact
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*} %Make itemize environment more compact

\usepackage{lipsum} % for placeholder text

\begin{document}

\noindent\textbf{\large XXXXXX} \hfill Email: XXXXXX\\
XXXXXX \hfill Mobile: XXXXXXX

\begin{center}
Github Link
\end{center}

\noindent\lipsum[1]\bigskip % intro text placeholder

\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X@{}} % @{} removes horizontal padding
\textsc{Experience}\\\hline
\end{tabularx}

\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{Auburn University} \hfill Auburn, AL
    \item[] \textit{Research Assistant \hfill Aug. 2020 - present} % The [] removes the bullet
        \begin{itemize}
            \item[] \lipsum[1] % Experience placeholder text 
        \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

You should be able to expand from there to make the rest of the resume. As for other sources to consult Overleaf has some nice [tutorials](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Learn_LaTeX_in_30_minutes) and you can usually also find an answer to a question right here on TeX.SE.

[image]

Comment: ! LaTeX Error: File `geometry.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Comment: @LoknathBasak `geometry` is in the LaTeX standard library, so you should be able to use it just fine. See https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry for instructions to install it manually.  In any event you can remove the `\usepackage{geometry}` line as well, it just changes the margin size.